# Calculating the Perron-Frobenius eigenvector of a positive matrix from limited information

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

In the background of this question is a matrix $A$, all of whose elements are positive.  The Perron-Frobenius theorem tells us that the eigenvalue with largest absolute value is real, and that there is an associated *dominant eigenvector*, all of whose elements are positive.

Suppose we don't actually observe $A$, but are told what its first row sum is.  We're also told the first row sum of $A^{2}$, $A^{3}$, $A^{4}$, ... .  In other words, writing $e$ for the vector of ones, we're told the first element of $Ae$, $A^{2}e$, $A^{3}e$, and so on.  If, for example, $A$ is a stochastic matrix then $Ae = e$ so that the information given is simply a list of ones: $(Ae)_{1}=1$, $(A^{2}e)_{1}=1$, etc.

This information is enough to work out the dominant eigenvalue of $A$ via the [power method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_method): simply compute $\lim_{n \to \infty} \left( (A^{n} e)_{1} \right)^{1/n}$.

My question is:

> Can anything at all be said about the dominant eigenvector?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The information you have does not determine the dominant eigenvector.

Let $G$ be the graph with vertex set $\{0,1,\ldots,7\}$ and adjacency matrix
$$
\left(\begin{array}{rrrrrrrr}
0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\\\
1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\\\
1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\\\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 \\\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0
\end{array}\right)
$$
Construct a second graph $H_2$ by joining a new vertex to the vertex 2, and a third
graph $H5$ by joining a new vertex to vertex 5. Then
$$
 (A(H_2)^k e)_2 = (A(H_5)^k e)_5
$$
for all $k$. (For $k=0,\ldots,8$ the actual numbers are 
$$
1,\\ 4,\\ 8,\\ 25,\\ 57,\\ 163,\\ 392,\\ 1073,\\ 2656)
$$
The Perron vectors are
$$
(1, 1, 1.579071, 1.460275, 1.019079, 1.168003, 0.5330099, 0.206667, 0.612263)
$$
for $H_2$ and, for $H_5$,
$$
(1, 1, 1.579071, 2.0725388, 1.631342, 2.134811, 0.974205, 0.377735, 0.827744)
$$

If you want positive matrices, take the sixth powers of $A(H_2)$ and $A(H_5)$. The relevant
property of $G$ is that the graphs $G\setminus2$ and $G\setminus5$ are cospectral, and their
complements are cospectral too.

All computations carried out in sage.

In a sense the problem is that you are getting a bit of information about each eigenspace,
whereas you want detailed information about a particular eigenspace.

Comment: Thanks @Chris, very nice!  Certainly this answers the implied question in my title.  I wonder whether there's anything at all (beyond Perron-Frobenius) that can be said about the dominant eigenvector, though?

If I'm not mistaken, knowledge of the *entries* of the first row for $A$, $A^{2}$, $A^{3}$, etc, is enough to reconstruct the whole matrix (at least so long as $A$ is not unipotent).  So I was hoping that knowledge of the row sums might at least provide some information about the dominant eigenvector.  But perhaps that's too much to hope for.

Comment: @Ian. An $n\times n$ matrix $A$ can be reconstructed from the vectors $x$,\dots,$A^{n-1}x$ if and only if these vectors span $\mathbb{R}^n$. But this is using $n$ times as much information.
Roughly speaking, in your case you can reconstruct one entry of each eigenvector. Fedja's answer provides another way of viewing this point.

Answer (score 5):

Assume that $v_1,\dots, v_n$ are eigenvectors and $\lambda_1,\dots,\lambda_n$ are eigenvalues. Assume also that $e=\sum_k v_k$. Then what you are given is merely $\sum_n (v_k,e_1) \lambda_k^n$, which, in a generic position, allows you to determine $\lambda_k$ and $(v_k,e_1)$ but no more than that. Now, take any matrix $A$ with positive entries, find the eigenvectors and eigenvalues, keep the eigenvalues but change the eigenvectors a tiny bit (respecting complex conjugation) by changing the coordinates of $v_k$ beyond the first to keep the identity $\sum v_k=e$. You'll get a new matrix with real entries close to the old one so it'll still have positive entries and the same sequence of observables but rather different eigenvectors.

Comment: Interesting - this gives a nice way to think about @Chris's last sentence.

There's one small typo, I think (though your intended meaning is clear): you write that we're given `$\sum_{n} (v_{k}, e_{1}) \lambda_{k}^{n}$` where I guess you mean that we're given `$\sum_{k} (v_{k}, e_{1}) \lambda_{k}^{m}$` for each $m$.

Answer (score 2):

There is some very partial information you can obtain. See this recent paper:

Das, Kinkar Ch.
A sharp upper bound on the maximal entry in the principal eigenvector of
symmetric nonnegative matrix. (English)
Linear Algebra Appl. 431, No. 8, 1340-1350 (2009). ISSN 0024-3795